# SQL Server Join with Latest 2 Entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I know the title of the post is bad but hear me out.  A question like this arose the other day at work, and while I found a way around it, the problem still haunts me.

Lets assume Stackoverflow has only 3 tables.

```
Users ( username )
Comments ( comment, creationdate )
UsersCommentsJoin , this is the join table between the first 2 tables.
```

Now lets say I want to make a query that would return the all the users with the last 2 most recent comments.  So the result set would look like this.

```
|username| most recent comment | second most recent comment|
```

How on earth do I go about creating that query ?  I solved this problem earlier by simply only returning the most recent comment and not even trying to get the second one, and boy, let me tell you it seemed a WHOLE lot more involved than when I thought with subselects, TOP and other weird DB acrobatics.

Bonus Round  Why do some queries which seem easy logically, turn out to be monster queries, at least from my rookie perspective ?

EDIT: I was using an MS SQL server.

Comment: FYI, only one question per question here.

Comment: The [`greatest-n-per-group`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) tag has many similar questions. You follow that link or the links under **Related** header, on the right.

Comment: It might help if you also included the DBMS you are using.

Comment: @ypercube The problem  is that I didn't know my problem was known as 'greaterst-n-per-group' in database jargon.

Comment: @Yes, I guesses so, too, that's why I added it :). It's a common problem (and tough to solve). The [greatest-n-per-group] tag is used in SO, no idea if it also used elsewhere.

Comment: Re: Bonus Round.  I think that part of the challenge is that most people learning SQL come to it from procedural languages that emphasize doing one thing at a time, and looping over the data if needed.  Suddenly thinking in terms of set operations is rather jarring.  Of course, if you're coming at SQL from an APL background you've already been jarred.

Comment: @user92546 I think you are right.  I felt my mind wanting to reach for some kind of collection and get the last two objects when solving this problem.  However, that isn't really the case because as you said, dbs are designed to work on sets, not objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a crosstab query pivoting on [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
WITH UC 
     AS (SELECT UCJ.userId, 
                C.comment, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userId 
                                       ORDER BY creationdate DESC) RN 
         FROM   UsersCommentsJoin UCJ 
                JOIN Comments C 
                  ON C.commentId = U.commentId) 
SELECT username, 
       MAX(CASE 
             WHEN RN = 1 THEN comment 
           END) AS MostRecent, 
       MAX(CASE 
             WHEN RN = 2 THEN comment 
           END) AS SecondMostRecent 
FROM   Users U 
       JOIN UC 
         ON UC.userId = U.userId 
WHERE  UC.RN <= 2 
GROUP  BY UC.userId
```

Comment: Thanks Martin.  It is apparent I am going to have to do some heavy reading if I want to get into more powerful queries.

Comment: @FlexFiend - Anything written by Itzik Ben Gan is well worth a read.

Comment: Thanks for "teaching me to fish" as they say.  I'm gonna see about acquiring one of these books and reading his website.