# Group By Proper Usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate

TL;DR How do I return columns without adding them to the GROUP BY clause in MSSQL ?  The criminal statement is below.

Hello Everyone,
So I recently asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243368/sql-server-join-with-latest-2-entries) and got a great solution which I was able to dissect and reassemble to suite my problem.  Here is the final result

```
WITH UC AS
(
    SELECT OSJ.opportunityid, OS.status,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OSJ.opportunityid ORDER BY creationdate DESC) RN
    FROM Opportunitystatusjoin OSJ
    JOIN OpportunityStatus OS ON OSJ.opportunitystatusid = OS.opportunitystatusid
)
SELECT O.opportunityid , O.salesperson ,
    MAX( CASE 
        WHEN RN = 1
            THEN UC.status
        END ) AS MostRecent ,
    MAX( CASE 
        WHEN RN = 2
            THEN UC.status
        END ) AS SecondMostRecent
FROM Opportunity O
JOIN UC ON UC.opportunityid = O.opportunityid
WHERE UC.RN <= 2
GROUP BY O.opportunityid , O.salesperson
```

Now if I want to return more columns from the Opportunity table i.e O.shoesize, O.favorite_color, I have to add them to my GROUP BY clause.  But I just get a dirty feeling because I am not trying to group the other columns, I just want them to show up with their respective opportunity.

A blog I found on the internet said to stuff your GROUP BY clauses as far in to your nested selects as possible.  However, since I am using the first statement ( "with UC...") that seems to make things less intuitive.  What is a smart way to include other columns from my table without adding them to the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 3):

If the columns are going to be the same value for everything you are grouping by, then you could do something like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, MAX(col3) FROM table GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Comment: I don't think the values for the columns will all be the same, as there will be varying shoesizes and favorite_colors for the Opportunities returned.

Comment: Then which ones do you want to list.  If you want to list all possible combinations you need to use GROUP BY.