# SQL Query all record in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a datatable like

```
CANDID  QID   OptID
11      56    116
11      56    117
11      57    118
11      57    119
11      60    124
11      60    125
11      60    126
11      62    129
11      62    130
11      62    131
```

How I can display this data like

```
CANDID   QID    OptID1   OptID2   OptID3   OptID4 
11       56     116      117      null     null
....
....

11       60     124      125      126      null
```

I tried this but this is not my desired output.

```
SELECT CANDID,
       QID,
       MIN(OptID) AS OptID1,
       MAX(OptID) AS OptID4
FROM   #TEMP1
GROUP  BY CANDID,
          QID
```

Comment: I doubt this will be ever possible, at least not easily since you have used a row-wise vector and now you want to project data as if it is inside of a column-wise vector.

Comment: What database system you're using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Join with Latest 2 Entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243368/sql-server-join-with-latest-2-entries)

Comment: You need to use `ROW_NUMBER` to get something to pivot on then pivot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining multiple rows into one row and appending the columns depending on the number of rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355100/combining-multiple-rows-into-one-row-and-appending-the-columns-depending-on-the)

Comment: @Martin Thanks for your help. I tried Row_NUmber that was making this so complicated that's why I put this on forum

Comment: `;WITH T AS(SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [CANDID], [QID] ORDER BY [OptID]) AS RN FROM #TEMP1) SELECT * FROM T PIVOT (MAX([OptID]) FOR RN IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) AS P`

Comment: Martin Smith you should put this solution as an answer, looks good when I run it on my system.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I already have done same in a little bit different way. But my result set is similar with yours. This is not what I am looking for If you compare the required result set I wrote in my question you will find it different.

Comment: @user1132134 - The result set is exactly the same. You just need to alias the columns. `SELECT CANDID,QID,[1] AS OptID1 ...`

Comment: @DavidSöderlund - I don't normally both VTC and answer but as SQL Fiddle seems to be down I will here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP1
    ([CANDID] int, [QID] int, [OptID] int)
;

INSERT INTO #TEMP1
    ([CANDID], [QID], [OptID])
VALUES
    (11, 56, 116),
    (11, 56, 117),
    (11, 57, 118),
    (11, 57, 119),
    (11, 60, 124),
    (11, 60, 125),
    (11, 60, 126),
    (11, 62, 129),
    (11, 62, 130),
    (11, 62, 131)
;

WITH T
     AS (SELECT [CANDID], 
                [QID], 
                [OptID],
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [CANDID], [QID] ORDER BY [OptID]) AS RN
         FROM   #TEMP1)
SELECT CANDID,
       QID,
       [1] AS OptID1,
       [2] AS OptID2,
       [3] AS OptID3,
       [4] AS OptID4
FROM   T PIVOT (MAX([OptID]) FOR RN IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) AS P 


DROP TABLE #TEMP1
```

Returns

```
CANDID      QID         OptID1      OptID2      OptID3      OptID4
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
11          56          116         117         NULL        NULL
11          57          118         119         NULL        NULL
11          60          124         125         126         NULL
11          62          129         130         131         NULL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin. This works absolutly spot on. I spent nearly a day to achieve what you have done in less than 10 mins.

Comment: Martin Please could you tell me how to add option_text with all optionId (OptID). I tried this way but no

Comment: Hi Martin, I have to add another column next to OPTID which is option description. this means every optid has its own descrption please could you tell me how to display this column.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.OptID) 
            FROM #TEMP1 c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')        

SET @query = 'SELECT CANDID, QID, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select CANDID
                    , QID
                    , OptID
                from #TEMP1
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 AVG(OptID)
                for OptID in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Returns

```
CANDID      QID         116         117         118         119         124         125         126         129         130         131
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
11          56          116         117         NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
11          57          NULL        NULL        118         119         NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
11          60          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        124         125         126         NULL        NULL        NULL
11          62          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        129         130         131
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin. This works absolutly spot on. I spent nearly a day to achieve what you have done in less than 10 mins.

Comment: Hi Azeem, I have to add another column next to OPTID which is option description. this means every optid has its own descrption please could you tell me how to to do this.